# Vue - binding an array from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've encountered this same scenario in several occasions, and wonder what am I missing.

Lets say I want to create a component that includes a list (a todo-list for simplicity) and an input field, used to insert todos to the list.
Now, I want to access this list from the parent component.

Surely using events to notify the parent for any change in the list, causing him to maintain it's own list synchronously isn't a good solution, and I should find a way to do it with a binding to the same list.

A second bad solution would be to init the list within the parent and pass it to the child as a prop, which is also bad since I want to decouple the list maintenance from the parent for abstraction.

The best solution I could think of is to handle the list within the child component, and on any change emit a change event to the parent with reference to the list (identically the same as change event of an input field), but I'm not sure if thats the most ideal way.

Any idea how to solve the issue? Sounds like a really common one, though I couldn't find any good solution online.

edit: just read about sync modifier that sounds pretty close to what i'm looking. Wonder if that is a good usecase to use it...

Comment: Imo, displaying data and fetching them should be separated. Having the child component to only display the data and the parent to fetching them is not a bad solution.

Comment: But that's not the case. I want the child to fetch/modify data, and the parent use it with as an http request argument (for example). Therefore, both the child and the parent should use the data, yet I want to keep it within the child for abstraction purposes.

Comment: In either case, the data should be fetched at the highest level possible to allow easy populate. If you want to share the data between a lot of components, just use VueX.

Comment: I do not agree with you. Sometimes you would want to create a generic component and use it later inside other components, and in order to keep the logic inside this generic component, you must manage init the list inside this component (otherwise you would not be able to modify it, and emitting events for the parent to modify the list will make you loose the genericity advantage)

Comment: You can create a generic component to display data and let the parent handle the task to fetch the data. In that case, the generic component does not care about how the data is fetched, so no dependency with Api. The generic component may only accept a list of objects with a given structure (with validation).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know Vue exactly but in angular we can use binding like this:

```html
<child-component #getChild></child-component>
<div>{{getChild.message}}</div>
<button (click)="getChild.childMethod()">Call child method</button>
```

In child component:

```html
childMethod() {
  this.message = 'child value';
}
```